# start ruby script onLoad ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

i want create simple application for notification in ubuntu...
For example: in 18:00, 21:00, 24:00 i want to receive message from ubuntu

simple method for message is:

```
def alarm
  %x{notify-send -i rhythmbox Test "Hello world" }
end

alarm
```

and when i sart this file ( like: ruby somefilename.rb )

i got notification message.

```
Question: how to cause this file run in 18:00, 21:00, 24:00
```

PS I know that there are many similar programs (for the experience like to know how to do that)

U.D. Using crontab:

```
* * * * * %x{notify-send -i rhythmbox Test "Hello world" }
```

Every minutes should start this script - but nothing happend

in some examples i saw that instead of script we put path to them: something like this:

```
* * * * * ruby /home/Home/myDisk/somefile.rb
```

how open with ruby this file or launch  notify-send script in terminal without ruby ?

Comment: i started use cron job - but: i put next => * * * * * notify-send -i rhythmbox Test "Hello world"  => every minutes start this comand, but - nothing happend =(

Comment: Is my answer possibly useful to you? If so, can you upvote it? Otherwise I'd prefer to delete it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good tools are `cron` and `anacron`.

To do it in Ruby, one way is to use the Ruby `sleep` method:

```
seconds = 18 * 60  # 18 minutes * 60 seconds/minute
sleep(seconds)
alarm
```

To use your "wake up" times in a loop:

```
start = Time.now
for wake in [18, 21, 24]
  seconds = wake * 60 + start - Time.now
  sleep(seconds)
  alarm
end
```

Also see Ruby `Thread` to do alarms in parallel:

```
for wake in [18, 21, 24]
  threads << Thread.new(wake) {|wake|
    sleep(wake * 60)
    alarm    
  }
end
threads.each {|t| t.join }
```